# Weblogic forkRender option is rendering portlets twice

Tags: performance, weblogic, fork

I am working on an application deployed on Weblogic which has many portlets.
We have splitted them on different dashboards and made some performance tests. For improving the results we have edited the *.portlet* files for some portlets and added the following attributes: **forkable="true"**, **forkPreRender="true"** and **forkRender="true"**.
In the *.portal* file we have set **asyncMode="enabled"** and **treeOptimizationEnabled="false"**.

The problem we are having now is that after these changes were made, the portlets are loaded twice whithin their placeholder.

Any hint for the root cause of this behaviour, please reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused due some custom modifications made by us and not by default weblogic code. In some cases, these changes were duplicating the portlet instances.
The problem was solved after these changes were commented.